# Why is the performance of a neural network so different every run?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization

I'm working on a recurrent neural network (LSTM), and the accuracy of the network is completely different every run. I understand that there are differences because of random factors, but this extreme?

[image: acc]
[image: loss]

The settings are completely the same in each run. I use the rmsprop optimizer (using keras and tensorflow) with default values. The test accuracy (random taken test set, 25%) is also between 50% and 98%

Can anyone tell me a reason for this?

Comment: How much data do you have?  How many features?

Comment: Assuming these runs have the same specification and train/dev/test splits, there are any number of things that could be going on. If you look closely at the loss curves, you'll notice some have an apparent "floor" (spikes are only in the positive directions). I have seen this occur when: (1) too little data for the complexity of the model; (2) highly imbalanced data; (3) features with very little variance within classes (analogous to separation in logistic regression). There could be many other reasons. I suggest taking a close look at your data.

Comment: This could also be related to poor initialization of weights.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have highly unbalanced data, and the test accuracy is very much dependent on which samples happen happen to go to the test set.

Comment: Am I right that in this case one could perform a repeated run with the *same* test set to find out whether the instability is at least due to the selection of the test set, or due to the randomness in the algorithm?

Comment: Yes, also you best make sure your test set is representative of your training set: roughly the same class distribution, similar percentage of outliers, etc.